Comparing efficiency of two queries
I am learning SQL, and while working through guided examples, I like to attempt writing my own query to answer a question before seeing how the lesson suggests doing it. In this case, I used a somewhat different approach, and I'm interested in comparing my method to the given example.
The guided example uses a public dataset available on BigQuery called bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike. The problem posed is to find Citibike rides with trip durations that most exceeded the average trip duration for its starting bike station.
Here is the code suggested in the guided example:
SELECT
  starttime,
  start_station_id,
  tripduration,
  (
    SELECT ROUND(AVG(tripduration),2)
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
    WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id
  ) AS avg_duration_for_station,
  ROUND(tripduration - (
    SELECT AVG(tripduration)
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
    WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id), 2) AS difference_from_avg
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips AS outer_trips
ORDER BY difference_from_avg DESC
LIMIT 25

And here is the code I came up with before looking at their solution:
SELECT
  starttime,
  start_station_id,
  tripduration,
  station_averages.station_average AS station_avg,
  ROUND (tripduration - station_averages.station_average,2) AS diff_from_station_avg
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
  JOIN (
      SELECT
        start_station_id AS station_id,
        ROUND(AVG(tripduration),2) as station_average
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
      GROUP BY station_id
    ) AS station_averages
  ON start_station_id = station_averages.station_id
ORDER BY 5 DESC
LIMIT 25

Looking at my code versus theirs, I thought mine would run more quickly, because I'm only calculating the average trip duration for each station once, when making the JOIN table. Their code, on the other hand, calculates each station average as many times as that station appears in the table.
In order to compare the two approaches, I put them each in a BigQuery tab, and after running them and verifying that they do the same thing, I looked at the "Job Information" for each query. The first one, supplied by the course I'm taking took "0 seconds", and mine took "1 second".
In order to see the comparison better, I tried editing the final line of each query to
LIMIT 250

...and then 2500, and 25000, etc. Their query kept running just about 1 second faster than mine, until I increased the limit all the way to 2.5 million. Then, mine ran in 17 seconds, and theirs ran in 18 seconds.
Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? Was my understanding of the code correct when I guessed that my query was more efficient? Why did the processing time scale differently for theirs and mine? Why does changing the limit even affect the time, when it has to calculate all results for every row in the table before it can ORDER BY column 5?
I hope these questions make sense. Thanks in advance for any insignts.

I dont know if the second query will give them same result as first one however when checking performance , you have to look at the query plan , what are the indexes is being use , how much is the cost and cardenality(num of rows), so you have get the query plan for two queries and check if an index needed, or re write in a way for an index to consider it, as why why 2.5m took the same time bcz you are now selecting large number of data so maybe its taking full tabe scan,

@Baalback they certainly seem to give the same results

Hi @G Tony Jacobs, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer

@SouravDutta per my experience on Math Stack Exchange, which I've been using for years, I generally wait a day or two to accept an answer, just because a lot might happen and I don't like to jump the gun. Thank you for your answer, and it looks like I'll probably accept it later :)

As commented by @Baalback when checking performance , you have to look at the query plan , what are the indexes is being use , how much is the cost and cardenality(num of rows), so you have get the query plan for two queries .
However to make your query more efficient  or evaluating the query performance in BigQuery , it depends on some factors :
Many of these factors can be observed through the query plan. A query plan  is generated for each query submitted to BigQuery. We can see execution statistics such as bytes read and slot time consumed.

On your query Applying a LIMIT clause to a SELECT * query does not affect the amount of data read . use SELECT * EXCEPT to exclude one or more columns from the results. Query only the columns that are needed . It can execute your query faster .

Reduce data before Join

Avoid WITH clause as prepared statement

Avoid oversharding of tables


You can go through this link   Optimize query computation and do your query more efficient and execute quickly .

This answer is helpful; thank you. I do have one (initial) question, though. Where do I find this "query plan"?

Thanks for the question ,you can go to Execution details tab in Bq console of the Query results .In that tab you can find the query plan along with  query execution time, slots consumed etc.
More details you can go through this
Link once  .
